# Mongodb not authenticating on localhost or connecting authenticated mongodb compas

Tags: mongodb

#### System

Hi I am running mongodb on ubuntu 20.14.
Im running mongodb with **systemctl**

#### What I've done

I've tried to make it more secure by adding an admin user and enabled authentication.
Ive restarted the service multiple times.

config file:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

How I created user:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
    user: "username",
    pwd: "123456",
    roles:["root"]
})
```

#### Problem

I am still able to connect through mongodb compass without any auth??? Im able to do everything even tho I enabled the authentication?
I am not able to login authenticated using these urls:

```
mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/
mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017?authSource=admin
```

Im sure the config file is loading since authentication works in console and I can see the right config load in the mongod.log

Comment: Strange, did you restart the service?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes I did

Comment: I've changed the port which gets loaded when I look at the log.
But I can't connect with compass to the new port but I can with the old port.

Comment: Can you run `db.adminCommand( { getCmdLineOpts: 1  } )` in order to check the real parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I thought the issue was with mongodb compass.
So what I did was deleting the application and when I did that I saw that I had mongodb installed on my pc too.

I was never connecting to the mongodb that I have created on my ubuntu server but on my own pc.

Answer (score 1):

It would be this one:

```
mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017?authSource=admin
```

See also: [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470)

Yes, even without authentication you can connect to Mongo database in any case. However, apart from harmless commands like `db.help()`, `db.version()`, `db.getMongo()`, etc. you cannot execute anything.

You can skip parameter `enableLocalhostAuthBypass`. The localhost exception applies only when there are no users created in the MongoDB instance.

Comment: That url doesn't work either.
When I connect without authentication Im able to create databases and collections and drop these ect.
I also removed `enableLocalhostAuthBypass` and that did nothing. 
I've updated my question.